# Find the shortest element in an array. Java. Weird error

Tags: java

```
public class  Sentence {                                                                   
private static String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "name", "is", "Bob"};

public String shortest(){                       
int shortestelement = 0;                    
String shortest ="";                        
for(int i = 0; i<words.length;i++){         
    if(shortest.length()<=words[i].length())
        shortest=words[i];                  
public static void main(String[] args) {                 
System.out.println("Shortest word"+words.shortest());
```

Now the error when ran is "Java: cannot find symbol. Symbol: method shortest().Location: variable words of type java.lang.String[].

This is probably a very stupid error.

Comment: Your code seems to be missing just a few closing braces.

Comment: You're missing closing braces for the for loop and the method `shortest`

Comment: Your code is totally incorrect, too many problems to list them all.

Comment: @JeremyW - Not to mention the method `main` and the class `Sentence`. :)

Comment: @TedHopp Haha yepp, those too.

Comment: Wow wow @JeremyW  Okay I left the braces out when i copied it on here. But what do you mean on the method main and class sentence error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call `shortest` by reference to `words` which is an `Array` of `String` and therefore does not contains the `shortest` method which explain the `cannot find symbol`

`shortest` is located in the `Sentence` class... If you want to call it from the `main` then you need to declare it `static`. Change

```
public String shortest(){
```

To

```
public static String shortest(){
```

Then change

```
System.out.println("Shortest word"+words.shortest());
```

To

```
System.out.println("Shortest word"+Sentence.shortest());
```

By the way, by convention, java method should follow the `camelCase` rules.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Your algorithm in `shortest` method is also wrong, here a snippet that would works :

```
public String shortest(){                       
    String shortest="";

    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++){     
        if(shortest.isEmpty())
            shortest = words[i];
        else if(shortest.length() > words[i].length())
            shortest=words[i];      
    }

    return shortest;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that the test for `shortest.isEmpty()` is correct. If the shortest word in `words` happens to be the empty string, you won't return that unless it happens to be the last word. It would be better to initialize `shortest` to `null` and check for that instead.

Comment: @TedHopp There is a lack of detail here, I agree with you, but from another point of view I don't consider an empty String as a word, while if the array is correctly named, it should contains only words. Anyway, this will give OP the wanted result for the example array he gave us.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `words.shortest()` with `new Sentence().shortest()`.

Comment: Works for me when I add `return shortest;` to `shortest()` method, but gives wrong result.

Comment: I think, OP has an error in logic. String `""` will always have zero length, so his `shortest()` method will always return empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class  Sentence {                                                                   
    private static String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "name", "is", "Bob"};

    private static String shortest(){                       
        int shortestelement = 0;                    
        String shortest ="";                        
        for(int i = 0; i<words.length;i++){         
            if(shortest.length() > words[i].length()) {
                shortest=words[i];
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {                 
        System.out.println("Shortest word: " + shortest());
    }
}
```

Comment: The logic in the `if` test in `shortest()` is backwards.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions would make your algorithm to find shortest value even simpler.

Convert your `String` array to a list and use `sorted()` to compare and sort your list in ascending order. Finally, use `findFirst()` to get the first value of your list (which is shortest after sorting).

```
String[] words = new String[]{"Hello", "aadsads", "adssadsadads", "aaa"};
String shortest = Arrays.asList(words).stream()
        .sorted((e2, e1) -> e1.length() > e2.length() ? -1 : 1)
        .findFirst().get();
```